# Exponential fit with the least squares Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a very specific task, where I need to find the slope of my exponential function.

I have two arrays, one denoting the wavelength range between 400 and 750 nm, the other the absorption spectrum. x = wavelengths, y = absorption.

My fit function should look something like that:

`y_mod = np.float(a_440) * np.exp(-S*(x - 440.))`

where `S` is the slope and in the image equals 0.016, which should be in the range of S values I should get (+/- 0.003). `a_440` is the reference absorption at 440 nm, x is the wavelength.

Modelled vs. original plot:

[image]

I would like to know how to define my function in order to get an **exponential fit** (**not** on log transformed quantities) of it without **guessing beforehand what the S value is**.

What I've tried so far was to define the function in such way:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * (x-440))
```

And it gives pretty nice matches

[fitted vs original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFI2Y.png).

What I'm not sure is whether this approach is correct or should I do it differently? 
How would one use also the least squares or the absolute differences in y approaches for minimization in order to remove the effect of overliers?

Is it possible to also add random noise to the data and recompute the fit?

Comment: Would you show the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: To handle outliers check [robust fitting](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html) in python

Comment: @mikuszefski, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is the same as the one described in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for scipy's `curve_fit`.

The problem you're incurring is that your definition of the function accepts only one argument when it should receive three: `x` (the independent variable where the function is evaluated), plus `a_440` and `S`.

Cleaning a bit, the function should be more like this.

```
def func(x, A, S): 
    return A*np.exp(-S*(x-440.))
```

It might be that you run into a warning about the covariance matrix. you solve that by providing a decent starting point to the `curve_fit` through the argument `p0` and providing a list. For example in this case `p0=[1,0.01]` and in the fitting call it would look like the following

```
curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=[1,0.01])
```

Comment: Thank you Ignacio, this is just what I've done and it works!

Comment: @PEBKAC bear in mind that your updated question, the fitted function is missing the offset in the exponent. I'd say that's giving you a worse fit. You can add that as a fitting parameter or put it as a constant.

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted the version without the offset, which at the end wasn't used. Thanks for warning me. At the end I used the right thing ;-) Many thanks again!